# Did the photo of a woman and a pony really exist?

Tags: slaughterhouse-five

I found a rather interesting reference in Slaughterhouse Five by Kurt Vonnegut:

> Weary had a block of balsa wood which was supposed to be a foxhole
>   pillow. He had a prophylactic kit containing two tough condoms 'For
>   the Prevention of Disease Only!' He had a whistle he wasn't going to
>   show anybody until he got promoted to corporal. He had a dirty picture
>   of a woman attempting sexual intercourse with a Shetland pony. He had
>   made Billy Pilgrim admire that picture several times.
>
> The woman and the pony were posed before velvet draperies which were
>   fringed with deedlee-balls. They were flanked by Doric columns. In
>   front of one column was a potted palm. The Picture that Weary had was
>   a print of the first dirty photograph in history. The word photography
>   was first used in 1839, and it was in that year, too, that Louis J. M.
>   Daguerre revealed to the French Academy that an image formed on a
>   silvered metal plate covered with a thin film of silver iodide could
>   be developed in the presence of mercury vapor.
>
> In 1841, only two years later, an assistant to Daguerre, André Le
>   Fèvre, was arrested in the Tuileries Gardens for attempting to sell a
>   gentleman a picture of the woman and the pony. That was where Weary
>   bought his picture,, too-in the Tuileries. Le Fèvre argued that the
>   picture was fine art, and that his intention was to make Greek
>   mythology come alive. He said that columns and the potted palm proved
>   that.
>
> When asked which myth he meant to represent, Le Fèvre, replied that
>   there were thousands of myths like that, with the woman a mortal and
>   the pony a god.

Is there any mention of this event ever occurring? It is like Vonnegut to mix up fictional and non-fictional characters and events and this one definitely did fit in nicely in his cynical portrayal of humanity anyway.

Does anyone have any reliable info on this one? Could it possibly be that it took only two years after photography was invented that it was first used in pornography? Or maybe it was an existing urban legend? Or Vonnegut just made it up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rumor was actually perpetuated by Slaughterhouse 5 itself, that is the earliest reference available of "that" anyway. It was used in a number of other locations, but the earliest is by Vonnegut.

I find his works are usually filled with these entertaining false histories.

The reason this particular picture is impossible is because a "Daguerreotype" photograph took 20 minutes to develop. Hardly useful for capturing the described scene.

Comment: Could you name some of the "other locations" you mentioned where this false Daguerreotype shows up?

Comment: @JacobFord I'll look this up again later, but I don't mean the "false daguerrotype" specifically. I'm referring to the "woman and shetland pony" trope, which has been used in on-screen jokes (typically spoken) to allude to bizarre ...adult media. Vonnegut appears to be the progenitor of said trope.

Comment: Ah! I see, got it. In fact, I just discovered it also shows up in a [fictionalized interview](https://books.google.ca/books?id=bLQeOR_m2YMC&lpg=PA143&vq=penis&pg=PA143#v=onepage&q&f=false) with Kurt Vonnegut, by Kilgore Trout (Greg Mitchell).

Answer (score 1):

*Slaughterhouse Five* may have popularized this rumor, but this photo was first referenced in *God Bless You, Mr. Rosewater*. Or at least a version of it that bears an unignorable comparison - like many elements in Vonnegut's literary collection. Unless this passage of *Slaughterhouse Five* was written before *Mr. Rosewater* was, which could be possible since Vonnegut mentions how long Slaughterhouse took him to write... But *Rosewater* was published first, so:

In *God Bless You, Mr. Rosewater*, Lila, Amantine Buntline's young daughter, was selling nudey photos and erotic literature to other children, and she sold a pornographic picture involving a Shetland pony to Fred Rosewater's son. Fred finds it and is disgusted.
"But it turned out to be a pornographic picture that little Franklin had bought that morning from Lila Buntline, using money he earned himself in his paper route. It showed two fat, simpering, naked whores, one of whom was attempting to have impossible sexual congress with a dignified, decent, unsmiling Shetland pony." (pg. 140)

It is not the exact same picture, but it is much like Vonnegut to use one name or concept with variations across works. Look at Kazak! The dog from space in *The Sirens of Titan*. But just a seeing eye dog in *Galapagos*. Also in *The Sirens of Titan*, Tralfamadorians are an entirely different creature from what they are in Slaughterhouse Five. Aliens still, but different from the “plumbers friends” in Slaughterhouse. (I would provide a quote but my copy of *The Sirens of Titan* is currently loaned out)

Interestingly, Vonnegut says that little Lila is also selling Henry Miller, among other smutty authors. Miller occasionally mentions Shetland ponies in his filthy tirades.
"Sometimes I had a mind to ask her if she had ever let herself be fucked by a Shetland pony." *Sexus*, pg. 233.

Hopefully this helps to straighten out the Vonnegut infundibulum for some folks.